# Geometric collision detection

Tags: c#, collision, detection, bounds

I'm having trouble with a particular area of my code. I'm trying to create a rectangle over a button, and when the cursor is inside the rectangle, the button will change to a red color.

```
private bool rectangleContainsPoint(
        Vector2 rectanglePos, 
        Texture2D rectangleImage, 
        Point targetPoint)
    {

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int)rectanglePos.X, (int)rectanglePos.Y,
                                        rectangleImage.Width, rectangleImage.Height);

        if (targetPoint.X < rect.X)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (targetPoint.Y < rect.Y)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (targetPoint.X > rectangleImage.Width)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (targetPoint.Y > rectangleImage.Height)
        {
            return false;
        }

        else
            return true;
    }
```

After looking over this a dozen times, I can't see why this doesn't work.

Comment: `rectangleImage.Width + rect.X`. Same for `Y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the width to X and Height to Y

```
else if (targetPoint.X > rect.X + rectangleImage.Width )
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (targetPoint.Y > rect.Y + rectangleImage.Height)
        {
            return false;
        }
```